# camel aws-sqs route stops consuming messages abruptly from aws queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

HI I am using camel out of the box aws-sqs route to consume our messages from the amazon sqs queue .The configuration we have is as below

```
    <from
            uri="aws-sqs://{{queue.inbound.object.updates}}?accessKey={{amazon.sqs.accessKey}}&amp;secretKey=RAW({{amazon.sqs.secretKey}})&amp;deleteAfterRead=false&amp;delay={{amazon.sqs.outbound.delay}}&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll={{amazon.sqs.outbound.maxmsgperpoll}}" />
        <log message="Got from SQS Messaging Queue: ${body}" />
```

here the amazon.sqs.outbound.delay= 2000 and maxMessagesPerPoll=10 .What we have observed in our prod environments in that the consumption does start for some hours but then the route stops consuming messages until we manually stop and start the sqs route .Also post this step we have a couple of routes which further process the messages consumed .

Have any of you faced such issues if yes please help .The load we receive on the queue ranges at around on an average 1000 + messages in a day

Comment: Just a question to confirm. Are you deleting the message once you read it? Cause in the url above delete after read is set as false

Comment: Hi @Rohit yes we are deleting message via Camel synchronizer post processing them programatically .Though post consuming messages we process those 10 messages in a multithreaded way via a threadpool.

Comment: And what are the chances that you are not able to delete the messages before within the visibility timeout time period?

Comment: ideally we should be able to delete all messages at the synchronizer once we process that .. how can that cause contention as we dont see any message in flight when it gets stuck